# launchy gem terminates tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, tdd, capybara

I've got a simple spec

```
describe "Workers" do
  describe "user attempts to view workers" do
    context "admin logged in" do

    end
    context "non-logged in user" do
      before do
        visit workers_path
      end

      it "should redirect to home page" do
        page.should have_content 'You are not authorized to access this page.'
      end
    end
  end
end
```

This passes just fine.  If I add `save_and_open_page`, the test run terminates and the output says "Process finished with exit code 0", but says nothing of the test status.

```
describe "Workers" do
  describe "user attempts to view workers" do
    context "admin logged in" do

    end
    context "non-logged in user" do
      before do
        visit workers_path
      end

      it "should redirect to home page" do
        save_and_open_page
        page.should have_content 'You are not authorized to access this page.'
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Capybara: 2.1.0

launchy: 2.3.0

rspec:  2.13.0

rails:  3.2.13

Comment: In your description, you mention 'save_and_load_page' but in your code you have 'save_and_open_page'. The 'save_and_open_page' is correct.

Comment: @Rebitzele - Definitely a typo.  Fixing that.  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Must have been a bad install of launchy.  I downgraded to launchy 2.2.0 and everything worked, then I upgraded (back) to launchy 2.3.0 and things seem to be working fine.